# How would I go about encoding a video from an array of images like a time-lapse?

Tags: arrays, swift, image, video

So I have been trying to do this for ages with no luck, ive found some solutions on git hub but these arent working for me, basically I have an array of UIImage which I want to be converted into a 10 second long video when the user presses a button, this video will then be saved to the users camera roll, does anyone have any code to deal with this in **swift**?

EDIT: The question which this has been marked as a duplicate from is answered in objective c, not **swift**

Comment: The answer from the page suggested is on objective c not swift thanks anyway

Comment: I think the intent of the closer was that, given the names of the library classes that expose this functionality and the general code flow, it shouldn't be too hard to come up with the equivalent Swift code on your own.

Comment: I have done very little objective c in the past so it would be very hard for me to translate. I've seen that question before and if I could translate it I wouldn't be here asking the question